# Javascript image slider transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a code, which adds a transition after the picture changes.
Here's my code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function displayNextImage() {
        x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
        document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
    }

    function displayPreviousImage() {
        x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
        document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
    }

    function startTimer() {
        setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
    }

var images = [], x = -1;
images[0] = "1.jpg";
images[1] = "2.jpg";
images[2] = "3.jpg";
</script>

<body onload = "startTimer()">
<img id="img" src="1.jpg"/>
</body>
```

Is there any possible way to add some transition when the code changes the image?

Comment: Not when there's just one image to work with. If you want a transition, you will need to create a second image, transition it in some way, and then replace the target at the end of the transition.

Comment: You can take a look at [this example](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly for example a fadeIn effect must be:

```
function fadeIn(elementId, miliseconds) {
  var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
  el.style.opacity = 0;
  var op = parseFloat(0);

  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op >= 1.0)
      clearInterval(timer);

    op += 0.1;
    el.style.opacity = op;
  }, miliseconds);
}
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/jAC72neLPp2OcYmGxp4L?p=info) you have a working example with your code and some additions

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, I've seen your code, still doesn't seem to have any transition in it.

Comment: @VigiMenyhártGyula Sorry, I updated the solution for a simple fadeIn transition, playing with this you can get a fadeOut too, if it's any help please vote up

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain more of this code? I've imported it in my project, but still nothing happen's.